# Use position of current node to access value of another node

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

I have an xml source that approximates a table layout (output from a program) - a is the table holder, b hold the column headings d, c are the rows and e are the row cells:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <a>
    <b>
        <d/>
        <d/>
        <d/>
    </b>
        <c>
        <e/>
            <e/>
        <e/>
        </c>
    </a>
</xml>
```

I have written the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Lessons>
    <xsl:for-each select="//c">
        <xsl:call-template name="lesson" />
    </xsl:for-each>
    </Lessons>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="lesson">
    <Lesson>
        <Teacher>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(./preceding-sibling::*)+1" />
            <xsl:value-of select="//b[count(./preceding-sibling::*)+1]" />
        </Teacher>
    </Lesson>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first xsl:value-of of the Teacher element gives me the correct values. I would like the second xsl:value-of to return the value of the heading for that cell i.e. for the first e element that calls the template the first d element is returned and so on. However, it ouputs the value of all of the d elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if it is not entirely clear what you expect, I will  try an answer.
As I understood you like to find the  `<d>` element which has the same position than the `<e>` element.

This is either possible with getting the current position as a variable.

```
xsl:variable name ="pos" select="position()" />
<xsl:value-of select="//b/d[position() = $pos]/@id" />
```

or use  count of `preceding-sibling`

```
<xsl:value-of select="//b/d[(count(current()/preceding-sibling::*)+1)]/@id" />
```

**Update** the part below is changed because of the comment from "George of all trades".

Be aware that the result of `position()`depends on the calling context.

For example following test xslt (version 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Lessons>
            <!-- Wrong result with position  -->
            <xsl:for-each select="//c/e">
                <xsl:call-template name="lesson" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Lessons>
        <Lessons2>
            <!-- Wonted result even with position -->
            <xsl:for-each select="//c">
                <xsl:for-each select="e">
                    <xsl:call-template name="lesson" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Lessons2>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="lesson">
        <Lesson>
            <Teacher>
                <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(./preceding-sibling::*)+1" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:variable name ="pos" select="position()" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$pos" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="//b/d[position() = $pos]/@id" />
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="//b/d[count(current()/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/@id" />
            </Teacher>
        </Lesson>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xml>
    <a>
        <b>
            <d id="d1"/>
            <d id="d2"/>
            <d id="d3"/>
        </b>
        <c>
            <e id="e1"/>
            <e id="e2"/>
            <e id="e3"/>
        </c>
        <c>
            <e id="e21"/>
            <e id="e22"/>
            <e id="e23"/>
        </c>
        <c>
            <e id="e21"/>
            <e id="e22"/>
            <e id="e23"/>
        </c>
    </a>
</xml>
```

Generates this output:

```
<Lessons>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e1,1,1,d1,d1</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e2,2,2,d2,d2</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e3,3,3,d3,d3</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e21,1,4,,d1</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e22,2,5,,d2</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e23,3,6,,d3</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e21,1,7,,d1</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e22,2,8,,d2</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e23,3,9,,d3</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
</Lessons><Lessons2>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e1,1,1,d1,d1</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e2,2,2,d2,d2</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e3,3,3,d3,d3</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e21,1,1,d1,d1</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e22,2,2,d2,d2</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e23,3,3,d3,d3</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e21,1,1,d1,d1</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e22,2,2,d2,d2</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
  <Lesson>
    <Teacher>e23,3,3,d3,d3</Teacher>
  </Lesson>
</Lessons2>
```

Comment: Using position() works for the example but for a more extended situation, position() gets the value of the node within a rtf rather than the original document and so breaks down if there is more than one c element

Comment: However, <xsl:value-of select="//b/d[(count(current()/preceding-sibling::*)+1)]/@id" /> did the trick. To clarify for other users, the important factor was placing the count() function inside () - that way the value of the function is returned as a number, rather than as a function. If it is returned as a funciton, it is ignored with a result that the value of d[] is returned - explaining the multiple values that I was getting the first time round.

Comment: Glad I could help you. (Even if I did not read the request correctly in the first place; sorry for that). But I think your explanation is not right. Not the parentheses "()"  are the "trick" (should also work without them. Impotent is to use the `current()` instead of the dot ".". (`[count(./preceding-sibling::*)+1]`) should do.